# What is the cheapest Google Compute Engine architecture for sharded MongoDB development setup?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, scaling, sharding

After weeks of developing my various microservices, GC Pub/Sub and GC Functions using a basic MongoDB server, I would like to test the entire data flow using what I would use in production: a sharded MongoDB cluster. I've never used these and would like to get myself familiar with setting them up, updating, etc.

Costs are an issue at this stage, especially for testing. Therefore, what is the most cost-effective way to setup a (test) MongoDB sharded cluster on Google Compute Engine?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach for you is to use [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/) for your deployment. It will let you choose the number of nodes and the machine types. In that way you can deploy something that suits your budget. You will [get billed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) according to the resources you deploy and can use this [online calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to have an estimate. A drawback is that there does not seems to be a direct way to increase nodes or change machine types without [manual reconfiguration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/).

While configuring your deployment the appropriate number of nodes and an arbitre will be created. Once you have tested, you might want to think about using [more complex architectures](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-mongodb#example_architectures) that will be redundant against failures in one region (Those will certainly increase your cost since it will mean having additional nodes).

You can also consider running [Mongo on GKE](https://github.com/pkdone/gke-mongodb-demo), it would be easier to escale but it will require that you get familiar with Kubernetes. [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) is also charged according to the resources used by the cluster.